# IE9 is auto-submiting form when <a> links clicked

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

While using IE9, every  link (when clicked) the search form is being submitted. Every link seems as if it is redirecting to the action value of the search form.

There is no java script attached to the form element.

```
<form action="/my-search-url" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the order of the form elements. Apparently the original developer decided to place the submit button before any input elements. By putting the submit input last (or removing it) fixed this issue.

```
<form action="/my-search-url" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```